# How to do TCP/IP binding from config file in WCF as opposed to default wsHttpBinding

Tags: wcf

How to add TCP endpoint to the service in WCF?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to add TCP endpoint to the service is modify you web.config file with respect of "WCF Service configuration editor". You can find it in the "Tools" menu of Visual Studio of in context menu of web.config (also in VS). You need add new endpoint with netTcpBinding. The address of such new endpoint will be start with "net.tcp://". For more information you can read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949080.aspx.

A good review of new features of WCF 4 you can find in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx